# Java - hashtable return any value or any key?

Tags: java, hashtable

Let say I have such Hashtable:

```
Hashtable<Object, Object> test = new Hashtable<>();

test.put("t", 1);
test.put(2, "t123");
test.put(3, true);
```

How could I just return any value from it or get any key from this hash table without knowing any key or value? Should I just iterate it and get first value or maybe there is some simpler better way?

Comment: I think it has entrySet() method, which might help. But why a hashtable instead of arraylist or array? Why do you need string keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant "any":

```
test.keys().nextElement();
```

or

```
test.element().nextElement();
```

Comment: Thanks. This one is simple and good. And yes I meant random or any:)

Comment: random means distributed well across your sample space, which is not happening here.

Comment: I know what it means, but I as you can see author wrote "yes I meant random or any".

Comment: @RuslanOstafiychuk Then he should change the question to `any` not `random` in the original question.

Comment: @Trying "return any value or get random key" (maybe he added it later)

Answer (score 1):

You can put all entries into a List and then use a random index to retrieve a random entry.

```
Hashtable<Object, Object> test = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

test.put("t", 1);
test.put(2, "t123");
test.put(3, true);

List<Entry<Object, Object>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<Object, Object>>(test.entrySet());
Random random = new Random();
Entry<Object, Object> randomEntry = entries.get(random.nextInt(entries.size()));

Object randomValue = randomEntry.getValue();
Object randomKey = randomEntry.getKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a random element from a hashtable in O(1), but the most efficient way to do it in O(n) would be something like this:

```
int chosenIndex = (int) Math.random()*map.size();
    i = 0;
for (Object v : map.values())
  if (i++ == chosenIndex) 
    return v;
```

BTW never use the `Hashtable` class, which is still around only for backwards compatibility. Use `HashMap`.

Comment: I think we are gone too ahead, OP want `any` key it seems i.e. just throw the first value. See the discussion below. :)

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But since the wording of the question implies a random element, this page could still be reached by someone actually needing a random element from a hashtable.

Comment: Marko Topolnik very true.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new   HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(10, "ddsadas");
        map.put(23, "sdss");
        map.put(24, "sdss");
        map.put(90, "sdss");
```

---

now random key generation `O(N)`:

```
        int size = map.keySet().size();
        int index=(int)(Math.random() * size)+1;
        System.out.println(index);
        for(Integer i : map.keySet()){
            if(index==1){
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
            else{
                index--;
            }
        }
```

You can achieve this in `O(1)` by putting there set in to an array and generate a random number among the array index and just return the value in the index of array. This is `o(1)`.